# sqlacodegen doesn't make any Tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I'm running a PostgreSQL database on a server and I'm trying to connect to it using SQLAlchemy. I found that [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) was a good tool to generate the MetaData object automatically along with its Tables. But when I try and run `sqlacodgen postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:5432/dbname`, I only get this:

```
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import MetaData


metadata = MetaData()
```

The connection string is definitely correct, and the database is up - I ran a small Python script using that connection string to connect to the database and used `execute` to run a query on it, and it returns exactly what I expected.

I'm not sure where even to start with debugging this. What could I do to see what's wrong? Is there some sort of requirement that `sqlacodegen` has that I'm missing?

Comment: looks like the question is incomplete. I think you forgot to add the error message.

Comment: @ArunBalakrishnan There is none, to clarify. I get the empty file, which I did include in the question. Anyway, this question is quite old now and I can't dig up the scenario I had here. Maybe I should just delete it?

Comment: yes, now I see what you mean. I got a similar output and then understood your question. You should keep the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out this problem was unrelated to `sqlacodegen`. All the tables in my database are prefixed with `dbname`. Passing in `--schema dbname` works.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and all tables are in the public schema. Got any tips for me?